# How does ps censor my password

Tags: security, password, ps, mongodb

I am playing around with MongoDB on my localhost and when using `ps aux | grep`, I got this

```
ubuntu   26701  0.2  0.6  96011 27851 pts/3    Sl+  11:14   0:00 mongo -u mongouser -p xxxxxxxx -authenticationDatabase tmpdb
```

the `xxxxxxxx` part is not censored by me, I invoked `mongo` client with password from command line. How does `ps` know it's sensitive info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ps` does not know that this is a password, so it can't "censor" it.  The `mongo` client, on the other hand, knows this and rewrites its command string so that people can't look at it with `ps`.

Note that there is a brief (very brief) instance between launching `mongo` and `mongo` rewriting its command line string.  In this brief moment, the output from `ps` *would* include the password.

The password is also stored in your shell's command line history file.